# How to use free jqgrid search and view toolbar buttons outside its toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

free jqgrid search and view buttons are used in its toolbar like:

```
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", {
    iconsOverText: true,
    search: true,
    del: true,
    add: true,
    view: true,
    refresh: false,
    edit: false
},
```

There are also other buttons in toolbar. Toolbar has too many buttons to be used in mobile devices. Less frequently used buttons should be placed into single separate bootstrap combo button and invoked outside of jqgrid.

How to invoke search and view  commands outside jqgrid and remove those buttons from jqgrid toolbar.

Buttons can removed by setting search and view to false. How to invoke those buttons in this case from external buttons?

Similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011126/how-to-replace-top-level-toolbar-with-bootstrap-3-navbar-in-free-jqgrid has no answers.

This question asks to keep most frequently used buttons like add, delete and some custom buttons in jqgrid toolbar and invoke other buttons from application settings combo button outside of jqgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search are View buttons of navigator bar are very simple. There just calls `searchGrid` or `viewGridRow` method of jqGrid. Before calling of `viewGridRow` one should get the rowid of selected row (`selrow` parameter of jqGrid) and use it as the parameter of `viewGridRow`. The method `searchGrid` have no required options.

Thus you can call `searchGrid` or `viewGridRow` methods in your code directly without usage `navGrid`. You can do this inside of `click` or `touchstart` event handler of your custom button.

Comment: Are those methods part of public API ? Will they available in future also ?

Comment: @Andrus: `searchGrid` is the method described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#calling_conventions) and `viewGridRow` is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#viewgridrow). I hold compatibility to the previous 4.x.y versions of jqGrid. Because of that I use the version numbers 4.10.0 (4.x.y too). I don't plun currently to remove some existing (old) methods from free jqGrid.